# XPath - How can I query for a parent node satisfying an attribute presence condition?

Tags: python, xml, xpath

I need to query a node to determine if it has a parent node that contains a specified attribute. For instance:

```
<a b="value">
    <b/>
</a>
```

From b as my focus element, I'd like to execute an XPath query:

```
..[@b]
```

that would return element **a**. The returned element *must* be the parent node of **a**, and should not contain any of **a**'s siblings.

The lxml.etree library states that this is an invalid XPath expression.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't combine the `.` or `..` shorthands with a predicate.  Instead, you'll need to use the full `parent::` axis.  The following should work for you:

```
parent::*[@b]
```

This will select the parent node (regardless of its local name), IFF it has a "b" attribute.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know about the lxml.etree library but `..[@b]` is <strike>fully valid XPath</strike> (**Update**: see Ben Blank's comment). Identical to `parent::a[@b]`, it will return context at the `a` element.

Comment: Adjusting to the parent::a[@b] format works nicely. Thank you.

Comment: @eddiegroves — "..[@b]" is *not* valid XPath.  You cannot combine the . or .. shorthands with a predicate.